# How to mock the method from parent class with EasyMock

Tags: java, superclass, easymock

```
public abstract class A{
    public int methodInA(String a){
         return 0;
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    String a = "ANYTHING";
    public void main(){
        int b = super.methodInA(a);
    }
}
```

This code is just an example. I am trying to test `B` and want to mock the method `methodINA` with arguments from `B`. Can I do this with EasyMock and if so how?

Answer (score -2):

This is not what mocking is for, you should be mocking the method `main` but that makes the test pointless as you won't test the actual code just EasyMock.

EasyMock (and mocking in general) is used when you want to control the behaviour of an object used by an object under test.

In your case the only option you have is to subclass B in your test, like this for example:

```
@Test
public void testSomething()
{
  final int expected = 5;

  B b = new B()
  {
    public int methodInA(String a)
    {
      return expected;
    }
  };

  b.main();

  //Add assertions here.
}
```

Comment: In my case, A is parent for many classes. I want to mock the method in A so I can focus on B and don't need to mock the behaviors in method of A every time I write unit testing for its child class. Use subclass may still need a lot of repeated work in my case. Do you have other solution for this?

Comment: The specialization of `B` doesn't need to be in the test method or even the test class but you will need to specialize `B` somewhere to achieve what you want.  When you use a mocking API you are in effect creating an new implementation of the mocked interface/class - in the case of an interface this is done using a dynamic proxy or with a class byte code manipulation - that behaves according to expectations you set.  The mocking APIs do not invoke methods on a class if you haven't set an expectation.

Comment: The problem here sounds more like a problem with your design - rather than inheritance consider using composition where you have one class that provides `methodInA` and instances of that class are injected into instances of `B`.  This way you simply mock the class that provides the `methodInA` and inject the mock when creating `B`.